Chess proof game after Black's 12th move reaches a draw?
A remark by Benjamin Wang reminded me of this puzzle (A.Buchanan, 2021)
What's the entire proof game leading to this position, where Black's 12th move has just drawn the game.

(To be precise: in formal chess problems under the Codex, there are 4  ways of drawing a game. Firstly, the rules for stalemate and draw by repetition are always in force. Moreover, in "retros" (such as this problem), the fifty move & dead position rules also apply. There's no decision-making or choice involved: if at any point, the criteria are satisfied, the game is over. These default settings can always be over-ridden if necessary by specifying in the problem stipulation.)
Have fun! :)

It may be wise to delete (before you get too many upvotes here) and re-post without a citation as the link has a solution (I didn't click it). Editing wouldn't help because of edit history. You can add the source after a solution is posted.

@BenjaminWang if someone wants to see the solution, why shouldn't he be able to click through? That's what people can do after someone posts a solution (below) anyway.

@BenjaminWang Thanks for the suggestion. If this was an entry in a solving set, I would absolutely not include a link that can lead to a solution, as it is, it's just for the fun of solving. Someone can still enjoy a book of puzzles despite the solutions appearing at the end of the book. Also folk can browse around from the link I included and find other puzzles

Laska, just out of curiosity: Would you happen to know if  rnbqkbB1/ppppppp1/8/8/7p/4PN2/PPPP2PP/RNBQKr2 would give a valid draw with PG in 10.0 moves? The essential difference being that rot13(rirel yrtny cynl va gur ercrngrq cbfvgvba zbirf gur juvgr xvat. Urapr, gurer pbhyq unir orra ab pnfgyvat va nal cbffvoyr shgher bs guvf cbfvgvba, rira gur svefg gvzr nebhaq. Qb gur evtugf fgvyy pbhag nf "vagnpg", rira vs ab pnfgyvat pna rire gnxr cynpr va gur shgher?)

@TimSeifert rot13(Ab guvf nzovthvgl jnf nqqerffrq va gur SVQR Ynjf n srj lrnef ntb. Pnfgyvat evtugf qrcraqf fvzcyl ba jurgure gur ebbx be xvat unir zbirq, abg ba shgher cebfcrpgf sbe npghnyyl pnfgyvat. Ba gur bgure unaq r.c. evtugf qrcraq ba jurgure gur r.c. pna npghnyyl or rkrphgrq (v.r. ab qverpg be vaqverpg cva). Gur nccebnpurf gb gur gjb fcrpvny zbirf znl frrz vapbafvfgrag jvgu bar nabgure, ohg vf npghnyyl gur zbfg orfg jnl, vzub.)

Ah I see. Thanks a lot for explaining this! I'm not sure if I like the rule being this way, but at least it is very clear :)

E.p. right would seem bogus if the e.p. can't be played. But if it's going to be played, it must be played immediately, so it's easy to check. On the other hand, any actual castling might have to be much further in the future, so difficult to check. It's just so much easier to look at whether the K & R have moved. A minor lacuna remains in the rules: currently capturing an unmoved rook does not eliminate the relevant castling rights. But sensibly everyone supposes that it does eliminate those rights

This is a very clever puzzle with a surprising solution!
To start finding it, we must first realize that the game was necessarily drawn by threefold repetition as anything else is clearly off the table. The shortest possible repetition is also easy to spot - it is given by

 ||: 1. Kf2 Be3 2. Ke1 Bd2 :||.

But soon after, some confusion sets in: Apparently, there is almost no pressure anywhere in the task! Each of these three games (all in the same Lichess study) seem to achieve the task, with clearly many more variations possible!
So, does that mean that the puzzle is flawed? Surprisingly, the answer is NO, and to find it, we need to realize that none of the games so far had a threefold repetition in them after all! Are you able to spot the difference between
this

 

and this

 

position? If you squint your eyes just right, you will notice that they differ in

 castling rights!

And after this realization, we can start to properly solve the puzzle:
In the final position, White has no more castling rights, since the king necessarily had to move out of this check twice. There are in principle two ways to break these rights - either by moving the king or by moving both rooks.
To see which of these is possible, we will first have a look at the move counts. To reach the diagram position (after the repetition), the white pieces had to move at least 8 times (3 knight moves, 1 pawn move and 4 king moves). However, achieving this minimum necessitates that Black had to push the a pawn all the way to a3. Doing so then uses up all of the 12 moves at Black's disposal (4 pawn moves, 2 queen moves and 6 bishop moves), all of which are then uniquely determined.
On the other hand, if Black does not push the a pawn all the way, White has to spend 4 additional moves to capture it (since no knight currently attacks the a-file). As this uses up all available extra moves, we cannot spend any more time breaking the castling rights, which makes this option impossible.
As such, we conclude that Black's a pawn must be captured on a3, which uniquely determines every move of the black pieces (not necessarily their order though) and gives White exactly 4 extra moves to get rid of the castling rights.
So, do we break them by moving the king? I claim that the timing of the black queen's arrival on a4 prevents this. The move Qh4-a4 must happen on Black's 6th move or later, since all black pawn moves must have happened before. But only after her arrival can White play f4 and Nd4. In addition to the four king moves involved in the final repetition, we conclude that there is no time to break the rights after Qa4. But, if it happened before, White must have played f3 earlier to allow the king to move. Since this uses up one waiting move, the white king can only make two moves (since there are no triangles available). But this means that the white king was necessarily on the line of sight from the black queen on h4, which also could not have been blocked by another piece using only a single additional move.
Altogether this shows that we must instead break the rights by moving both rooks! Since this uses up all four available moves, there is no more flexibility in the move order. It is clear that we have to start with the h rook, since the a rook can only move once the knights captures Black's a pawn. And with that, it all falls into place, as can be seen in this final solution:

 1.Nf3 a5 2.Rg1 a4 3.Rh1 a3 4.Nxa3 e6 5.Rb1 Qh4 6.Ra1 Qa4 7.Nd4 Bb4 8.f4 Bxd2 9.Kf2 Be3 10.Ke1 Bd2 11.Kf2 Be3 12.Ke1 Bd2 draw

Thanks for posting this nice puzzle Laska, it was a lot of fun to work out! :)

A very accurate solution - and thanks so much for the kind words :)

Haha, I like the use of the musical repeat to indicate the repetition. First time I see it used in non-musical context

I don't get how you reach the conclusion of the castling rights. If you assume that before the 3-fold repitition white already lost their castling rights, then there is a unique solution which you deduced. If you do not assume white lost there castling rights there are lots of other solutions. But how do you justify that white must have lost their castling rights?

@quarague The position on the board can only be repeated if White moves their king. As such, the rights are definitely lost in the end, which means we have to break them before the repeating can even start

So if you don't lose the castling rights beforehand you would need one more move in the repeating cycle because the first one that loses the castling rights wouldn't count as identical to the later ones?

@quarague Yes, exactly!
